# Firebase auth, get uid before page loads instead of "null"

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, use-effect

I'm trying to query my firestore and I need the uid for the query. My issue is that when my page loads and I run the query, I get `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'uid')`.  The uid isn't retrieved by the time the page loads. When I reload localhost from my terminal, the query runs just fine and my desired info is shown, since the auth has loaded.

In an attempt to solve this, I've placed my query and data retrieval inside a useEffect()

```js
useEffect(() => {
        const getStories = async () => {
                const q  = query(storiesCollectionRef, where("authorId", "==", auth.currentUser.uid))
                const data = await getDocs(q);
                setStoryList(data.docs.map((doc) => ({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})));
        };
        getStories();
    }, [auth]);
```

I know that giving a useEffect() dependencies will cause it to reload when these dependencies update. I've tried leaving it empty `[]`, putting `[auth]`, and putting `[auth.currentUser]` as dependecies as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66752231/firebase-reactjs-useeffect-typeerror-cannot-read-property-uid-of-null) post, but nothing has worked.

I need to get the uid before my page loads so that the correct information is displayed to the user. I'd appreciate any help!

**Edit:**
Since I couldn't get it working, my temporary solution is to implement my query logic in my map. I would still really appreciate any insight on how to resolve this properly, as getting all the documents and then refining based on uid seems improper.

```js
 useEffect(() => {
        const getStories = async () => {
                //const q  = query(storiesCollectionRef, where("authorId", "==", auth.currentUser.uid))
                const data = await getDocs(storiesCollectionRef);
                setStoryList(data.docs.map((doc) => ({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})));
        };
        getStories();
    }, []);

return(
{storyList.map(story => {
                        return auth.currentUser.uid === story.authorId ?
                            <Storybook title={story.title}/>
                            :
                            <></>
                    })}
)
```

It takes a second for the information to render properly but at least there's no error.

Answer (score 1):

You should delay running the query until `auth` is available. Currently you are trying to run the query when auth is not defined and hence getting the TypeError.

If uid of currentUser coming from auth is not defined, stories array will simply be an empty array and you should just have to deal with that particular case. You could do something like this:

```
...
const [storyList, setStoryList] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const getStories = async () => {
            const q  = query(storiesCollectionRef, where("authorId", "==", auth.currentUser.uid))
            const data = await getDocs(q);
            setStoryList(data.docs.map((doc) => ({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})));
    };
    auth.currentUser.uid && getStories();
}, [auth.currentUser.uid]);

return (
  storyList?.length > 0 && storyList.map(list => ...)  
)
...
```

Comment: I tried implementing this solution but I am getting the same error - `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'uid')` but this time at the line where I define my dependency array as [auth.currentUser.uid]. I also want to add that it is guaranteed that the user is signed in at this page, as it's inside a protected route based on authentication state.

Comment: then put auth in dependency array and try auth?.currentUser?.uid && getStories().

Comment: This eliminates the error, but now the information isn't loading -- getStories(); never runs.

Comment: that means there's no currentUser object or uid in currentUser. Can you show me the part where you defined auth?

Comment: Yeah sure, auth is defined in my firebase-config file, by using firebase's getAuth() function `export const auth = getAuth(app);`. Auth is set when the user signs in with google. 
`const signInWithGoogle = () => {
        signInWithPopup(auth,provider).then((result) => {
            localStorage.setItem("isAuth", true);
            setIsAuth(true);
            navigate("/");
        })
    }`

Comment: Try putting auth.currentUser in dependency array. I noticed auth is not null even if you're unauthenticated. If that doesn't work there's probably something wrong with your authentication. Try console logging auth.currentUser to see if you can see the information of currently signed in user includign uid

Comment: No error - but again getStories() is not running. Same thing with the console log - it just doesn't fire. I appreciate your time in looking into this, I'll try to look for another solution.